# How to detect the loss of 3G data connection in symbian QT

Tags: qt, symbian

Is there a possible way to detect that my phone has lost  3G data connectivity(Not the WIFI) and register  some sort of No data event to be scheduled and sent to a distant server.

I have found the use of MConnectionMonitorObserver (Please refer to the code below) but I don't really know which case should I use to fire the desired event : is it EConnMonStatusUnattached or EConnMonStatusSuspended or EConnMonPacketDataUnavailable ?

```
void ConnectionObserver::EventL(const CConnMonEventBase& aEvent )
{
    switch(aEvent.EventType())
    {
        case EConnMonConnectionStatusChange:
        {
            CConnMonConnectionStatusChange* realEvent;
            realEvent = (CConnMonConnectionStatusChange*) &aEvent;
            TInt connectionStatus = realEvent->ConnectionStatus();

            if (connectionStatus == EConnMonStatusNotAvailable)
                return;

            switch(connectionStatus)
            {
                case EConnMonStatusActive:
                    //Connect status is active

                    SaveConnectionEvent("Connected");
                    break;

                case EConnMonStatusUnattached:
                    //Connect status is disconnected

                    SaveConnectionEvent("Disconnected");
                    break;

                case EConnMonStatusAttached:
                    //Connect status is connecting

                    SaveConnectionEvent("Connecting");
                    break;

                case EConnMonStatusSuspended:
                    //Connect status is suspended

                    SaveConnectionEvent("Suspended");
                    break;
            }
        }
        break;

        case EConnMonPacketDataAvailable:
        {
            SaveConnectionEvent("PDPAvailable");
        }
         break;

        case EConnMonPacketDataUnavailable:
        {
            SaveConnectionEvent("PDPUnavailable");
        }
         break;


         default:
            break;
    }
}
```